# Writing a C array to 3D volume in vtk format using array strides and grid spacing

Tags: c, data-visualization, vtk, scientific-computing

Suppose I have an array of floating points (malloced) and this array represents a 3d volume of `nx * ny * nz` with strides in the respective directions as `sx = 1`, `sy = nx` and `sz = nx * ny`. The grid spacing is say some constant `dx`. How can I write this data into a vtk file (I suppose vtkImage should be the format I should look at) for visualization in Paraview?

A minimal example for the data arrangement as described above is as follows:

```C
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /* array dim */
    int nx = 512;
    int ny = 512;
    int nz = 512;

    long int nt = nx * ny * nz; /* total values */

    /* strides */
    int sx = 1;
    int sy = nx;
    int sz = nx * ny;

    /* grid spacing (can be different as well, in which case rectillinear grid should be needed) */
    dx = 40.;
    dy = 40.;
    dz = 40.;

    /* allocation */
    float* data = malloc(nx * ny * nz * sizeof(float));

    /* fill up values */
    for (int k = 0; k < nz; k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
                data[sx * i + sy * j + sz * k ] = 5.0; // constant but could be a mathematical function
    }

    /* how to write this array to a vtk file ? */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the file format spec for this "vtk" file? Edit: Is [this](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/VTKFileFormats/) what you want to create? If so, what is the actual problem trying to do so?

Comment: I would also like to explore what should be the right vtk file format to go. For a uniformly spaced grid the vtkImageData (.vti) should do the trick, but supposedly the dx != dy !=dz, in that case, vtkRectilinearGrid (.vtr) or  vtkStructuredGrid (.vts) should work. The latter two will also handle the former much simpler case.

Comment: Focus on one problem at a time. I assume you aren't successful when trying to create the "vtk" file, right? Where does it go wrong? If you compare the file you create with what you expected, where does it differ? You haven't shown the code where you actually try to create the file so it's hard to say what you do wrong.

Comment: to be honest I haven't done it since I can't find any working example to get some motivation from. Hence, I thought someone might be having ideas on which I can proceed.

Comment: The page Ted linked to describes a toolkit. It also seems to describe the file format in a way that you could create your own API. But, I suspect the toolkit lib would give you the primitives to save/restore with just a few API calls. At a quick glance, it seems like the format is ascii/text headers followed by text data, similar to the [older] PPM formats. The toolkit also supports XML formats. Within the Ted's link, there is a link to the VTK users guide: https://www.kitware.com/products/books/VTKUsersGuide.pdf Also, look at: https://vtk.org/